# When do missed shots and/or suppression shot destroy objects?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

Mostly, indoor, a miss shot, or suppression destroy the wall behind target.
Sometime it destroy something useful(like navi computer) Sometime, the shot just go into sky. 
The chance go up when weapon get better (Laser, Plasma) 
Is it random, or do we have any chance do this on purpose ?
 Like on ancient Xcom (i mean DOS version long ago), we can command troop to shot at wall to destroy it.

Comment: In my experience plasma weapons tend to destroy covers much more frequently than lower tier weapons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways to deliberately destroy damageable terrain, but they involve grenades, rockets, properly timed destruction of Sectopods, Mechtoids, Ethereals or Cyberdisks or the MEC trooper's [collateral damage](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Collateral_Damage) special ability.

Missed shots' fire angle is randomly determined; if it hits something else the game determines then and there whether that type of weapons fire has the capability to destroy the object (or in the case of cars, set it on fire) and resolves on the spot.

Comment: So, is it possible to aim at one enemy, miss, and hit a different one? Or your own teammate?

Comment: No. A missed shot will sometimes destroy scenery, but it won't hit anyone else unless you were firing an AoE weapon (grenade, rocket launcher, etc).